# Why does cond appear to 'cache' an internal binding?

Tags: clojure, datomic

I am building Datomic transaction with this function, which I am then mapping over a list of input keywords:

```
(defn build-enum-transaction [inp]
  (cond
    (.contains (namespace (first inp)) "region")
       [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/region] :db/ident (first inp)]
    (.contains (namespace (first inp)) "sector")
       [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/sector] :db/ident (first inp)]
    (.contains (namespace (first inp)) "specialism")
       [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/specialism] :db/ident (first inp)]))

(defn build-all-enum-transactions [inp]
  (vec (map build-enum-transaction inp)))
```

The input data to the build-all-enum-transactions is:

```
([:region/EU]
 [:region/UK]
 [:region/NAFTA]
 [:sector/NON-CYCLICALS]
 [:sector/FINANCIALS]
 [:specialism/INSURANCE]
 [:specialism/VAT])
```

I get the following result:

```
[[:db/add #db/id[:db.part/region -1000289] :db/ident :region/EU]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/region -1000289] :db/ident :region/UK]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/region -1000289] :db/ident :region/NAFTA]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/sector -1000290] :db/ident :sector/NON-CYCLICALS]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/sector -1000290] :db/ident :sector/FINANCIALS]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/specialism -1000291] :db/ident :specialism/INSURANCE]
 [:db/add #db/id[:db.part/specialism -1000291] :db/ident :specialism/VAT]]
```

As you can see, the **:db.part/** should yield an incremental number for each however it only does so for each of the 'cond' clauses. Why is this? It appears as though the 'cond' is closing over the value and re-using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `d/tempid` to create a tempid at runtime. `#db/id` is a reader macro that will expand to a tempid when the program is read, i. e. compile time.